# I am having problem using jquery with Vite. Used rollup-plugin-inject but still couldn't seem to make it work

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vite, rollup

I was working with vue and vite. The project requires jquery functionality but it seems like vite does not allow jquery to be used in normal way. So I used rollup plugin inject to use the jquery. I followed an instruction that I got to use rollup plugin inject to make jquery work with vite. But after implementing that, I still does not seem to make it work.

So I tried the following in vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'
// define & and jQuery on the global window object

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({   // => that should be first under plugins array
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',       
    }),
    vue(),
    
  ],
  
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Also, in main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

After making these changes, I got the following warning:

```
[vite] warning: rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse D:/vespagiri/src/components/Header.vue. Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include
plugin: inject
File:D:/vespagiri/src/components/Header.vue
```

I was expecting the jquery to work but still no luck. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 . jQuery is UMD module and so is importable

Comment: It's either vite inject or import in main, not both at the same time. What does happen when you use import alone?

Comment: I have removed the inject and tried the import. import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = window.jquery = $. But nothings works yet.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is window.$ === undefined or something?

Comment: The jquery doesn't work. No error on the browser console. I just can not get jquery to work. For testing purpose, I added a simple jquery code to show an html inside a div in index.html page. But that also not working since jquery is not working.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a good technical description of the problem. It's unknown what's "simple jquery code" and what could be possible reasons for it to not work. What exactly does happen when you do `import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $` without using inject plugin? What does happen when you do `$()`? It's supposed to select an element, this could be easily debugged. In case it fails, what does `$` import debug to?